# wcf msmq binding in iis 6.0

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-6, hosting, msmqbinding

Hosting env : Windows 2003 server
IIS : 6.0

Dev env : Windows XP
IIS : 5.1

Scenario:

Client will be pushing some message into MSMQ and WCF service will be the one keeping an eye on MSMQ. Once the message is pulled from MSMQ WCF service will process and then put the data/message on to some other MSMQ.

We are thinking of creating a WCF service with NetMSMQ binding.

I have heard that if we are using IIS 6.0 we wont be able to host the WCF service with MSMQ binding, am I right? So for that reason are we supposed to host it as console app or windows service?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct - hosting in IIS 5/6 only works for HTTP protocols / bindings. If you want to use MSMQ, you'll have to host it yourself - in a console app or a Windows NT Service.

IIS7 on Vista/Server 2008/Win7/Server 2008R2 supports MSMQ through the Windows Process Activation Service (WAS).

Marc

Comment: But you should remember that WAS will not start the service automatically, only the first time someone sends a request to it.

Comment: @blowdart: yes, that's true - "on demand service activation" - this can be a good thing (tm) or a bad thing, depending on your scenario